# Why do I get the estimates in the scientific form ? in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a dataset and variables are in character class so I fix them and turn them to numeric and make a regression model but the estimates are in the form of :

(Intercept) 1.213e+04  1.197e+03

Why do I get estimates in this form? How can I solve it?

```
fix(Table5_5)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

MODEL2 = lm(Table5_5$SALARY ~ Table5_5$SPENDING)

summary(MODEL2)
```

Comment: You are getting that output because the values have different orders of magnitude. They are both printed with 4 digits, therefore, the scientific form is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your data but you could try to run `options(scipen = 999)` at the start of your sessiom. This should give you the result in decimals for the rest of your R session.

Answer (score 3):

You would print the coefficients like this:

```
model2coefs <- summary(MODEL2)$coefficients
```

and then enter this after setting up 'model2coefs'

```
format(model2coefs,scientific = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use round function on the model summary,

```
round(summary(MODEL2)$coefficients,5)
```

> Estimate Std. Error  z value Pr(>|z|)
> (Intercept)      -0.35621    0.10713 -3.32507  0.00088
> CreditScoreNew    0.00054    0.00021  2.60888  0.00908
> GeographyGermany -0.09686    0.05368 -1.80439  0.07117
> GeographySpain    0.04322    0.04944  0.87422  0.38200
> GenderMale        0.10161    0.04045  2.51193  0.01201
> AgeNew            0.01692    0.00195  8.66327  0.00000
> Tenure           -0.01943    0.00696 -2.79038  0.00526
> Balance           0.00000    0.00000  0.00498  0.99603
> NumOfProductsNew  0.04454    0.03668  1.21429  0.22464
> HasCrCard1       -0.04443    0.04418 -1.00576  0.31453
> EstimatedSalary   0.00000    0.00000 -1.04045  0.29813

accessing certain variable also returns full value

```
summary(MODEL2)$coefficients[3,]
```

> Estimate  Std. Error     z value    Pr(>|z|)
> -0.09686260  0.05368159 -1.80439146  0.07116996